# How to prove this factor of $a^n+b^n$ if $n$ is odd

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is:

> How to prove that $(a+b)$ is the factor of $a^n+b^n$ if and only if $n$ is an odd natural number?

I tried this using mathematical induction but failed.

I don't have any other idea to prove it. I am a 12 grade student. thank you

Comment: What do you mean is the factor of? if you mean $(a+b)|(a^n+b^n)$ if and only if $n$ is odd then it is not true.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Take $a=1=b$. Then it is true for all $n$. I think this is what dREaM meant.

Comment: @Clayton yeah, that's what I meant, it seems to work for $a=b$ in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the factor/remainder theorem for polynomials for this.

Let $p(a)=a^n+b^n$, then $(a+b)$ is a factor iff $p(-b)=0$

We then have that $p(-b)=(-b)^n+b^n$ and this is equal to $0$ if $n$ is odd and $2b^n$ if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

if you do the long division you will notice the following identity:
$$
a^n+b^n = (a+b)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k a^{n-1-k}b^k\right) +(1+(-1)^n)b^n
$$